# How to specify explicit locking while creating a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the default locking mechanism in PostgresSQL when we create a table ? is it row, page, table level or something else?

Is it possible to specify row level locking when we create a table ? something like below in Sybase.

```
CREATE TABLE user 
(...)
LOCK DATRAROWS
```

Or do we not need to specify any locking strategy and leave it to Postgres to choose the best while we dealing CRUD ?

Cheers!

Comment: I believe postgres always uses the least intrusive locking mechanism possible -- MVCC row level locking, in most cases.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: I'm coming from Sybase space, where we used to explicitly set lock datarows, and here in my specific use case, I don't want Postgres to use anything other than row level locking. Now I understand things are bit different in PGSql :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything you can specify at CREATE TABLE time for PostgreSQL. At run time, you can [select rows `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR SHARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE). If you're coming to PostgreSQL from another platform, you should skim the docs on [concurrency control](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no locking when you create a table.
Locking can be read here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/explicit-locking.html